# How to push both server and database as one image to docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile

So this is what my `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: docker
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: supersecret
      MYSQL_USER: superuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: supersecret
      DATABASE_HOST: db
  web:
    build: ./web
    image: `jonas/testapp:2`
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
```

Inside `web/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:10.16.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3333

CMD npm start
```

Running `docker-compose up` successfully works, the mysql image is being pulled and the web service connects to it, but when I do `docker-compose push` it looks like only the `jonas/testapp:2` image is being pushed to registry so whenever I do `docker run -it -p 3333:3333 jonas/testapp:2` on other computer, looks like the web service is only pulled and not the db service too.

Is it possible that when I run `docker run -it -p 3333:3333 jonas-testapp:2` on other computers, the `db service` in the `docker-compose.yml` is being pulled to? Or am I missing something here? or do I really need to pull the mysql image first and pull my image? Something like:

```
$ docker pull mysql:5.7
$ docker run -it -p 3333:3333 jonas/testapp:2
```

Comment: You need the `docker-compose.yml` to run both containers together.  (You _can_ reproduce this with two separate `docker run` commands, but there are several options that are either implicit or explicit in the Docker Compose config.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the image `jonas/testapp:2` is not aware of the dependency of the `mysql:5.7` image declared in your docker-compose yaml file.

You have two options:

- Share the docker-compose.yaml file with the other computer and run docker-compose from there
- Run both containers (mysql and testapp) using `docker run ...`

Comment: Ah thank you. You made everything clear to me now. So the reality is I have to run a container with mysql image and another one with my server. That's logical.